# Turn off Safari 9 blinking in web inspector?

Tags: safari, macos, web-browsing, websites

The web inspector in Safari 9 seems to have added this new "blinking" thing which I find somewhat annoying although it can be useful. How can you turn it off and on? Here is what I mean.

[image: blinking as content is manipulated]

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This can be done in the Elements tab by disabling this little brush icon:
[image: Enable Paint Flashing]

Comment: What a mystery!

Comment: Thank you, had to search for it; it's only visible in the elements tab (not in source)

Comment: That's what it says in the written text part of my answer :)

Comment: WTF isn't the option to turn this off with the rest of Apple's bewildering selection of nonsense under the `Debug` menu? "_Enable new block inside inline Model_"?  Whatever, Apple!